# Package xcolor Error with classicthesis

Tags: color, classicthesis

I am writing my thesis using classicthesis but i've been getting the same error over and over.

`` Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `CTtitle'. ... of the thermal conductivity}}{11}{part.2} ``

Here's the code (it's my first time on latex so feel free to give me some advice for my preamble)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
%Librerie utili
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{{Immagini/}}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0394}{\ensuremath{\Delta}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
            \begin{figure} [h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541.eps}
            \end{figure}
        
        \begin{center}
            {DIPARTIMENTO DI INGEGNERIA CIVILE E INDUSTRIALE\\ CORSO DI LAUREA IN INGEGNERIA AEROSPAZIALE\\}
            \vspace{18mm}
            {\LARGE\textbf{{Methods for identifying thermal characteristics of layered composites for space applications}}}\\
            \vspace{3mm}
        \end{center}
        
        \vspace{30mm}
        
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
        {Relatori:\\ Pr. Mario Rosario CHIARELLI\\ Pr. Daniele FANTERIA\\ Pr. Frédéric LACHAUD\\ Pr. Joseph MORLIER\\ Ing. Yohann LEDRU\\}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}\raggedleft
            { Candidato: \\ Francesco RIZZO\\ }
        \end{minipage}
        
        \vspace{15mm}
        
        \centering{\large{ Anno Accademico 2021/2022 }}
        
    \end{titlepage}
\afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
\cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{40mm}
\begin{flushright}
    \textit{Alla mia famiglia}  
\end{flushright}
    

    \afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace*{40mm}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \epigraph{Mettere citazione.}{Mettere autore}
    

    \afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
        Thermal management is critical to the performance, lifetime, and reliability of electronic devices. With the miniaturization, integration and functionalization of electronics and the emergence of new applications such as light emitting diodes, thermal dissipation becomes a challenging problem. Addressing this challenge requires the development of composite materials with enhanced thermal conductivity. In this work...
\end{abstract}
        \afterpage{\null\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \chapter*{Acknowledgement}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        \part{Composite material thermal properties }
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Statement of the problem}
```

here's the .log file

```
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\afterpage.st
y"
Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks31
\AP@partial=\box53
\AP@footins=\box54
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.st
y"
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip111

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.st
y"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks32
\ex@=\dimen197
))
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen198
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count291
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count292
\leftroot@=\count293
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count294
\DOTSCASE@=\count295
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box55
\strutbox@=\box56
\big@size=\dimen199
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count296
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count297
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count298
\dspbrk@lvl=\count299
\tag@help=\toks33
\row@=\count300
\column@=\count301
\maxfields@=\count302
\andhelp@=\toks34
\eqnshift@=\dimen256
\alignsep@=\dimen257
\tagshift@=\dimen258
\tagwidth@=\dimen259
\totwidth@=\dimen260
\lineht@=\dimen261
\@envbody=\toks35
\multlinegap=\skip112
\multlinetaggap=\skip113
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks36
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
) ("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count303
\float@exts=\toks37
\float@box=\box57
\@float@everytoks=\toks38
\@floatcapt=\box58
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/wrapfig\wrapfig.st
y"
\wrapoverhang=\dimen262
\WF@size=\dimen263
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count304
\WF@box=\box59
\WF@everypar=\toks39
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/nomencl\nomencl.st
y"
Package: nomencl 2021/11/10 v5.6 Nomenclature package

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.st
y"
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.
tex"
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils
.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks40
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks41
)
\XKV@depth=\count305
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbas
ic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip114
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box60
)
Package tocbasic Info: setting babel extension for `nlo' on input line 187.
Package tocbasic Info: setting babel extension for `nls' on input line 188.
\nomlabelwidth=\dimen264
\nom@tempdim=\dimen265
\nomitemsep=\skip115
)
\@nomenclaturefile=\write3
\openout3 = `document.nlo'.

Package nomencl Info: Writing nomenclature file document.nlo on input line 21.
   defining Unicode char U+0394 (decimal 916)

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backen
d-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count306
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box61
)
No file document.aux.
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(86.72377pt, 455.30124pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50793pt
* \paperheight=845.04694pt
* \textwidth=336.0pt
* \textheight=662.6498pt
* \oddsidemargin=58.48398pt
* \evensidemargin=58.48398pt
* \topmargin=-40.58768pt
* \headheight=15.95pt
* \headsep=21.42006pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=49.98015pt
* \marginparwidth=76.65019pt
* \marginparsep=21.90005pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)


("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-p
df.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count307
\scratchdimen=\dimen266
\scratchbox=\box62
\nofMPsegments=\count308
\nofMParguments=\count309
\everyMPshowfont=\toks42
\MPscratchCnt=\count310
\MPscratchDim=\dimen267
\MPnumerator=\count311
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count312
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks43
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epsto
pdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `alltext-nott'.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \showhyphens on input line 24.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-ppl.c
fg"
File: mt-ppl.cfg 2005/11/16 v1.6 microtype config. file: Palatino (RS)
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded.
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
Package caption Info: floatflt package is loaded.
Package caption Info: hyperref package is loaded.
Package caption Info: wrapfig package is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 24.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.s
ty"
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.
sty"
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\g
ettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count313
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 24.
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `document.out'.



LaTeX Warning: File `Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541.eps' not found on input lin
e 29.

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541.eps>
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541-eps-convert
ed-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant
541-eps-converted-to.pdf Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 29.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541-eps-converted-
to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 ...e=0.5]{Immagini/marchio_unipi_pant541.eps}
                                                  
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+fvm on input line 2
9.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file OT1fvm.fd. on input line 29.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fvm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 29.


("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-cmr.c
fg"
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 42--43

 []

[1

{C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]pdfTeX warni
ng (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already
 used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.54    \cleardoublepage
                       [1

] [2

] [3

]
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+zeur on input line 66
.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/eulervm\uzeur.fd"
File: uzeur.fd 2005/01/11 v4.0 (WaS)
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-eur.c
fg"
File: mt-eur.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS Euler Roman (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+zeus on input line 66
.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/eulervm\uzeus.fd"
File: uzeus.fd 2005/01/11 v4.0 (WaS)
)
("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-eus.c
fg"
File: mt-eus.cfg 2006/07/28 v1.2 microtype config. file: AMS Euler Script (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+zeuex on input line 6
6.

("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/eulervm\uzeuex.fd"
File: uzeuex.fd 2005/01/11 v4.0 (WaS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+zplm on input line 
66.
 ("C:\Users\franc\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1zplm.fd
"
File: ot1zplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
)
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `zplm' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
 [4

] [5

]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.74    \end{abstract}
                     [1

]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.76    \cleardoublepage
                       [1

]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has
 been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.80    \tableofcontents
                       [2


]
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `document.toc'.

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.3}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.81    \listoffigures
                     [3

]
\tf@lof=\write6
\openout6 = `document.lof'.

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.4}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.82    \listoftables
                    [4

]
\tf@lot=\write7
\openout7 = `document.lot'.

pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.5}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.83 ...rt{Composite material thermal properties }
                                                   [5

]

! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `CTtitle'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.83 ...rt{Composite material thermal properties }
                                                  
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[6

]
Chapter 1.
Package microtype Info: Character `013' is missing
(microtype)             in font `OT1/pplj/m/sc/10.95'.
(microtype)             Ignoring protrusion settings for this character.
[7

]

LaTeX3 Info: Redefining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'm' on line
(LaTeX3)     86.

 (document.aux

Package mparhack Warning: Marginpars may have changed.
(mparhack)                Rerun to get them right.

)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `document.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for `document.out':
(rerunfilecheck)             Before: <no file>
(rerunfilecheck)             After:  A9231F60A6D4E51BE321B15AABC82F96;194.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15119 strings out of 479696
 272555 string characters out of 2865178
 705312 words of memory out of 3000000
 31685 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 444318 words of font info for 192 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 120i,20n,124p,440b,517s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc
}<C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/publ
ic/fpl/fplrc8a.pfb><C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type
1/urw/palatino/uplb8a.pfb><C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fon
ts/type1/urw/palatino/uplr8a.pfb><C:/Users/franc/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 
2.9/fonts/type1/urw/palatino/uplri8a.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (14 pages, 84183 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 86 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 82433 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 89155 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The color `CTtitle` is defined in the `classicthesis` style file so this error is a bit strange. You could try to delete the `.aux` file. If that doesn't work then you need to provide a bit more information, i.e., code that is inside your document that reproduces this error.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to move `\usepackage[eulermath]{classicthesis}` to the top, directly after `\documentclass[11pt]{report}`.

Comment: Hi Marijn. Thank you for your feedback. I'll provide you with the code inside the doc since I deleted the aux file but nothing changed. Also when I moved classicthesis up the margins changed a bit but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried your code as posted, by adding `\end{document}` at the end and removing the image (that I don't have), and then it compiles without the error. Also the color of the part name (CTtitle, which is Maroon, which is dark red) is shown correctly). Could you try the same, i.e., make a new document with the code from your question and nothing else, and try to compile that?

Comment: Your error message is from the aux or toc file (table of contents). Delete the <main>.toc file and try again.

Comment: @Marijn I tried to run the code as I posted but even in this case no color is shown.

Comment: @user187802 I tried to delete my .toc file as well and to compile it but nothing changed

Comment: put \listfiles as first line into your document. Then run the file and insert enter if it stops until it is finished. Then provide the file list, which is at the end of the log file.

Comment: Maybe you have a locally changed version of `classicthesis.sty` that is missing the color definition for some reason, or a very old version? Indeed you can use `\listfiles` to check, you could also paste the relevant line in the log file where loading the package is logged (for the example in the question this is around line 114 in the log on my system)

Comment: I'm sorry guys but It is my first time using Latex. Do you want me to post my .log file after having put \listfiles as first line?

Comment: Yes, not the whole log file, but only the list of files at the end of the log file. If you can also post the other relevant lines from the log (any line that has the string `classicthesis` in it) then the information would be even more complete.

Comment: Thanks for the log file, but this is the middle of the file, we need the start and the end of the file as well. Preferably the log file for your example code in the question, which is shorter and has less messages that are not relevant for the issue.

Comment: It tells me the message is too long anyway

Comment: Can you view the full contents of the log file yourself? For pasting into the question here you can remove the current log information and add only the file list at the end of the log file, that should be around 100 lines of log information.

Comment: @Reverse the log you posted doesn't have the output of `\listfiles`, please add that. Also the log now starts at the `afterpage` package, this is already quite a bit down your list of packages past the part where the issue is, i.e., at `\usepackage{classicthesis}` and before. One possible cause is that another package is loading `xcolor` internally but with a different list of named colors, which causes the definition of `CTtitle` to fail - but to be sure we need to see the list of all the packages (and versions, and preferably paths) from the start up to `classicthesis`.

Comment: @Marijn can I upload the .log file directly on the forum?